# Inverter resultados de while

Tags: php, loop

Existe alguma função no PHP que me permita inverter a ordem de resultados de um `while`?

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte código que verifica se uma URL.

```
<?php
function url_exists($url) {

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return ($code == 200); 
}

$noticia=700;

while($noticia)
{
    if (url_exists($url = 'http://www.exemplo.com.br/noticia_'.$noticia.'.htm'))
    {
        echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a><br>';
        $noticia++;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Ele me traz as URL's da seguinte forma, gostaria que o resultado fosse do maior para o menor mas não sei se com meu código atual conseguiria.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode armazenar o resultado em um array e invertê-lo depois:

```
$arrUrls = array();
while($noticia)
{
    if (url_exists($url = 'http://www.exemplo.com.br/noticia_'.$noticia.'.htm'))
    {
        $arrUrls[] = $url;
        $noticia++;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}

foreach (array_reverse($arrUrls) as $url) {
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a><br>';
}
```